# How many power plants could plausibly be built in a given, relatively small area? For e.g. how many nuclear plants could be built in a 1000sq.km area?

Tags: economy, nuclear, power

For e.g. how many nuclear plants could be built in a 1000sq.km area?
How many gas/coal/oil plants could be co-located in a small area? Etc.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information or be more specific.  You could plausibly build as many as you could fit.

Comment: Just one, if it is big enough. Or thousands, if they are small enough.

Comment: If you stack them high, then the strength of materials would be a hard limit, else you can take them all the way into space. Please give us a bit more to go on.

Comment: Power plants, as in "something which generates electrical power" can vary a lot in size. I guess most assume you're talking about today's technology, but can you focus on one type of power plant : Nuclear, coal or gas? Also, are there specific constraints you want to be taken into account? For instance, today's nuclear plants need a stead stream of water (rivers...) to cool down the reactors, and coal needs a good logistic to provide sufficient input. Are we allowed to put as many water canals as we want? Shall we dismiss the logistic?

Answer (score 5):

A stereotypical [*Los Angeles*-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles-class_submarine) SSN occupies about 1,100 square meters (it's about 110 meters long and 10 meters across). Allowing 9 times this area for each sub we get 10,000 square meters. We can place 100,000 of them on 1,000 square kilometers of ocean. Each *Los Angeles*-class SSN has a nuclear power plant on board, generating [150 MW thermal / 50 MW mechanical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S6G_reactor). 100,000 of them would give 15,000 GW thermal / 5,000 GW mechanical. That is about 8 times the average total electric power generated in the USA.

Comment: Just use the reactors, no need for the rest of the war machine.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond - AlexP probably is worried the reactors wont work if they get soaked in salt water.    I wlll point out that each Los Angeles class sub has a draft of 9.7 m and so in addition to the 100,000 layer we could also stack them up.  Monterey bay is 1500 m deep and so allowing 0.3m for periscopes that is a stack 150 deep; 150 * 100000 = 15 million submarines and 22 million GW thermal!  That is 1000 times the output of all earths power plants combined!  But only a little less than half of the energy of all sunlight hitting the earth.

Comment: @Willk: And they also need their heat exchange circuits and the steam generators and the turbines to convert thermal power into mechanical power. All in all, most of the submarine.

Comment: @AlexP I was thinking you could put little crawl tunnels in between the submarines to allow sailors to move around in the stack from sub to sub.  But that would probably be silly.

Comment: @ 
Willk
 So scuba divers instead? Or the crew stays on board for months?

Answer (score 3):

The main limiting factors are the logistic of supplying the fuel and the availability of water to discard the waste heat.

While the first one can be engineered and optimized, the last one usually relies on having a body of water available (river, lake or sea) which can be dumped in with the lukewarm water coming out of the cooling towers.

Once you start dumping heat in the water, it heats up, and usually the max temperature at which the dump can happen is regulated by law (so I was told when I visited the nuclear power plant in Phillipsburg). So putting close together more plants will end up lowering third yield.

Together with this, you also need to consider that is not a smart move to concentrate a lot of power plants in the same area, because as soon as one of your neighbors decides to wage war on you, they have a very easy way to easily cut your legs.